# Importing multiple projects into eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am just curious to know, whether there are possibilities to import more than one project at the same time into Eclipse. Because whenever I create my new workspace I had to import the needed projects from my old workspace to my newly created workspace.

So it would be nice to know, if there are options to import multiple projects at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this link : [Multiple Projects Automatically Into Your Eclipse Workspace With Team Project Sets](http://java.dzone.com/articles/checkout-multiple-projects) and [Importing Multiple Projects into eclipse](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg15378.html)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If all of your old projects exist in a single directory or in a single parent directory, you can do **File -> Import... -> Existing Projects into workspace**.  Choose a root directory that is a parent all of the projects you want to import.  You will then be able to import all of the projects at once.

Comment: You can also import projects into workspace from an archive file. You'd have to go via `Existing Projects into Workspace` and not import from archive file though.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work (for me, at least) if the parent directory itself is also an Eclipse project.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, this is allegedly fixed in Eclipse 4.3: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=144610

Comment: @Andrew, I am able to multiple projects but they did not import as Java project they are just simple java project.

Comment: just to add .. if your project is MAVEN project . you can go to your PARENT POM.XML and select it. once selection is done,  you will be able to see all the related project.  click the checkbox side to the projects, which you want to import. And then click ok. All the related project will be imported in the workspace.

Comment: yes,it works..good solution @Andrew Eisenberg

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing experiment of an easier and smarter import mechanism for Eclipse IDE. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Smart_Import for details. Then you'll see new UI entries in File menu or Import wizard that will allow you to import projects recursively.

In case you notice any issue, please report bugs!

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***windows->showView-> Project Explorer-> Browse-> select workspace -> select all files.***

alternatively you can go to ***file-> import -> general -> file system -> workspace***