# Is there any way for eclipse to recognise projects created in the file system?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I know that if we put folders into an existing project and hit refresh, it recognises. But what I want to know is if I copy a project into an existing workspace and make eclipse recognise this.

I also **dont** want to Import because I am dealing a very large number of projects and importing each one is very manual process.

I am writing code to create projects inside my workspace but cannot get eclipse to recognise this. I also tried writing a plugin that would create projects whenever the methods are called.

Do I need to meddle with .project or .classpath files or is this even possible

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313858/importing-multiple-projects-into-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

If you select `File-->Import-->Existing Projects into Workspace`

you can select a directory(root folder), that can contain many folders (which are eclipse projects).

This lets you import many projects at once.

Comment: Thanks. Never realised that it was this simple. I thought it would create a high level directory with the folder and then have projects under that but that doesnt seem to be the case

Also this question has already been asked before but I thought this was different

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your project your new project. Eclipse will then recognize it as a project and offer it for inclusion in your workspace.

Comment: true, and if your project folder is already in the workspace nothing will be actually copied