# How to import nested java projects to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have a folder called "MyProject" and inside it I have 10 folders that each of them is a Java project (contains .classpath and .project). I don't want to import them one by one. Is there a way to import folder "MyProject" and all nested ones?
I tried `import>general>Existing project into workspace` but it didn't work.
Also I checked the option `search for nested projects` but it didn't work as well. I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269468/how-to-import-nested-java-projects-to-eclipse) but that is different from mine. In my case there is no parent project.

Comment: are those maven projects?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I use the Eclipse, I haven't ever tried doing what you asked. So I'm just going to redirect you to this link and hopefully it will help you: [Importing multiple projects into eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313858/importing-multiple-projects-into-eclipse) It's basically what you tried. Worked for me. When you choose a directory, you get a view of all the available projects and you just need to have checked those you want to import.

Comment: Please check my edit that question is not like mine.